# I don't understand how fgets is creating a seg-fault

Tags: c, file-io, stdio

I have an assignment to write a program that copies takes 2 arguments (filePaths) and copies the first file into the second.
As far as I can tell, I should I'm supposed to use fgets.
What I have seems to work, up until the end when I can't get detect the end of the file. According to everything I've read, it seems like fgets is supposed to stop when it hits the end of the file and return null or something, but if I let it this keeps reading the last line of the file.
Here's the code. I don't want answers (this is homework), I just want to understand what I'm doing, so I can get the answer myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 80

int readLineFromFile(FILE* file, char* buffer) {

    if(! *fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {
        return -1;
    }
    int length;
    for(length=0; buffer[length] != '\0'; length++);
    return length;
}

void writeLineToFile(FILE* file, char* buffer) {
    fprintf(file, "%s", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("incorrect number of arguments, 2 text files expected, recieved %d\n", argc - 1);
        return 0;
    }
    FILE* input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE* output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int charsRead = readLineFromFile(input, buffer);
    int i;
    while(0 < charsRead) {
        writeLineToFile(output, buffer);
        charsRead = readLineFromFile(input, buffer);
        printf("%d\n", i++);
    }
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look up the documentation for fgets. What exactly does it return when at the end of the file?

Comment: it returns 's' on a success or NULL on a failure, but the compiler complains whenever I try to compare the result to null. I don't really understand how null works in C, I pretty much started C about a week ago.

Comment: Compare the return of fgets() with NULL. `if(fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file) == NULL) {return -1;}`

Comment: Dereferencing a function is not a common C idiom btw. There's rarely a reason you should be doing something like that.

Comment: Do not dereference `NULL`.

Comment: Just a note: although you are working on text files you could use `fread` and read the file in blocks of a certain size.

Comment: @icaughtfireonce Please show your code whuch is trying to compare the result with null and rejected by the compiler.

Comment: `! *fgets` should be `! fgets`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the function dereferencing in `if(! *fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file)) {`. I changed `*fgets` to `fgets` and it ran fine. See the correct code [here](https://ideone.com/isYhqd). But for extra credit, figure out how to make this work with any filetype, not just plaintext.

Comment: To work with non-text files, put a `b` in the open-mode string. Also you probably want to use `fread` rather than `fgets`.